# Command not executing after installation Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: command-line, 18.04

- I'm using ubuntu 18.04 machine. I'm facing some issues from last few days. After installing some programs, commands aren't executing. Before some days, i had installed `nodemon` with `npm`. After installation i just execute `nodemon` and it says `Command 'nodemon' not found, did you mean..`. I tried restarting terminal and them my machine. Tried installing it globally and with `sudo` too.
- It happened again with me just now. With commands `ngx` and `firebase`.

What to do with this. Please comment if you need additional info.

Comment: Do `echo nodemon ngx firebase | xargs -L 1 which`

Comment: nothing to see on command. @George Udosen

Comment: That means 1) Wasn't installed correctly, or 2) Programs have different name from what you using.. How did you install these programs?

Answer (score 0):

Finally find the solution. It was npm issues. i won't giving me any error but just won't working says `command not found`. So it fixed by reconfiguring npm directory. Here is ref. https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally